# Android studio потеряла модуль

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Модуль есть но он его не видит]

Есть проект в студии, как вы можете видеть модуль существует в проекте, но он не воспринимает его. В чем может быть проблема и можно ли её решить не создавая новый проект?

Comment: перестроить проект пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, даже удалял папку Build, всё также

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

1. `"File->Sync Project with Gradle Files"`
2. Можно добавить facets:

`кликнуть правой кнопкой на проекте > открыть Module settings > Facets > Add facets ( "+" подписать на самом верху ) > Android после добавления могут появится модули`

1. Если у вас последняя версия студии:

`кликнуть правой кнопкой на проекте > открыть Module settings > Add module ( "+" подписать на самом верху ) > Phone and Tablet Application (тут вы можете создать свой модуль).`

вот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration) по вашей проблеме. Надеюсь смог чем-то помочь. Удачи :)